Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"] is serving wrong user
We have a legacy ASP.NET Webforms application that we are migrating to a new server cluster. The application is hosted in IIS and it uses Windows Authentication. The application makes use of the deprecated function
Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]

The application is served to end users via Azure App Gateway
We noted a very weird behavior: sometimes, when two users login to the application concurrently, the value of Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"] for one of the users is wrong, e.g., user A becomes user B!
We attempted to add cache-control headers to IIS, namely: no-cache, no-store, and it did not fix the issue.
We also confirmed that the issue does not happen when we access one of the servers directly, i.e. not via Azure App Gateway, so we are inclined to think it is a caching issue. But of course, we are open to suggestions.

The issue was that AppGw does not support NTLM/Kerberos protocol and can sometimes mix the user sessions. We decided to opt in to a different technique.
